# brunel not working on IBM data science experience

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I am trying to use brunel on a spark scala notebook on IBM datascience experience.

```
%AddJar -magic https://brunelvis.org/jar/spark-kernel-brunel-all-2.2.jar
%%brunel data(leadsDF) map x(state) y(count) color(state)
```

I always get this error:

```
Name: Error parsing magics!
Message: Magics [brunel] do not exist!
StackTrace:
```

Is there a import needed for brunel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this Scala 2.11 with spark 2.0 and it worked for me.

`%AddJar -magic https://brunelvis.org/jar/spark-kernel-brunel-all-2.2.jar`

Then i used below to display and it showed me the map.
`%%brunel data('co2agg') map(low) x(CO2_per_capita) color(Mean_Co2) tooltip(#all):: width=800, height=500`

Example reference is from 
https://github.com/Brunel-Visualization/Brunel/tree/master/spark-kernel/examples

I have fully functioning example here for scala 2.11:-
https://apsportal.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/97e83c35-06a2-476a-aa57-078a20f04356/view?access_token=8d2f4f749aab9abbf45a08351f7b50f7fb09f06ad9aa7bab5ebc9a2cc98e902f

I tested this with scala 2.10 and i get some dependecy error, i am guessing it is because of brunel 2.2 may be dependent scala 2.11.

I hope that helps.

Thanks,
Charles.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where magics where not working correctly. For me this action from the "Known Issues" fixed it:

> Run the following code in a Python notebook to remove the existing Scala libraries: `!rm -rvf ~/data/libs/*`